# How to create git branch from current files without changing master?

Tags: git, github, branch

I was working on a small update on the master branch, which quickly evolved into the new version of the app. However, I wasn't tidy enough to create a new branch from the beginning, so now I'm stuck being hugely different than the master branch and not being able to commit and collaborate.

Is there any way I can get my changes into a new branch ("labs" or something) and push them to github without affecting the stable master branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b labs
git push origin labs
```

The syntax of the latter command being `git push [remote-repository-name] [branch-or-commit-name]`

Comment: You have to actually commit changes between `checkout` and `push`.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh: Yeah, I figured when I pushed and it was a copy of master :P